# after using file.copy(path) and getting the new file i get the previos file at that location

Tags: flutter, file

I'm trying to update a locally saved image file (user's profile picture).

This is how I do it:

```
Future<void> setProfilePic(File newProfilePic) async {
String profilePicPath = (await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory()).path +
    Platform.pathSeparator +
    "profilePic.jpg";
await newProfilePic.copy(profilePicPath); }
```

Then I try to get the profile picture like so:

```
Future<File> getCurrentUserProfilePic() async {
String filePath =
    (await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory()).path + "/profilePic.jpg";
File profilePicFile = File(filePath); 
return profilePicFile; }
```

The profile picture I get is the previous picture located in that file.

Only after I reopen the app, the widget shows the new profile picture.

I do use await when calling the get function and I do setState().

Does anyone know what the problem is?

Comment: Do you await the set profile pic function before calling the getCurrentUserProfilePic?

Comment: @NazariiKahaniak yes, i used await on that aswell :)